# Cloud Build Github Pull Request Trigger does not fire on Pull Request Closed event

Tags: github, google-cloud-build

I am trying to setup a build trigger that would instanciate a mock server for the client i build to run integration testing.

When a PR is openned, a mock server should be instanciated in App Engine, then killed off upon PR merged or closed.

Setting up Github Trigger on Pull Request event seems to work fine.
It triggers:

- on PR creation => does deploy the service as expected
- on Reopening of a PR => does deploy the service as expected
- on each push on a branch that has a PR => i do not quite care for now
- on PR merged => does Not Trigger my script so i cannot delete the service
- on PR closed => does Not Trigger my script so i cannot delete the service

Trigger is a Gen1 Github Pull Request cloud build trigger.
I have provided it with a valid cloudbuild.yaml that does the job when invoked.

I have considered implementing PullRequest WebHook from Github, i decided against it since it would me having a webservice to map formats and security token verification.

I am considering trying Gen2 trigger, since i discovered it only is a mater of location and maybe they are implemented differnetly. Will keep you posted.